# How to Apply Same Jquery to Elements with Unique IDs Added Through CMS Over Time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, content-management-system

I'm building a page that currently contains a few videos and more will be added over time through our CMS (Craft). The container div for each video will have a unique ID, as below:

```
<div id="video-1"></div>
<div id="video-2"></div>
<div id="video-3"></div>
```

Every time one of the divs is clicked, I want to run some Jquery. It is the same base Jquery but I want it to only run for the unique video that is clicked, so it should be tied to the ID.

The challenge is - I don't want to have to go to our javascript file and manually add a new selector to run the function(s) each time we add a video. I would like the Jquery to work for each new video that is added through the CMS, without any extra steps. Assume that each video's ID will increase by as a new one is added.

Here is an example of the Jquery I'm working with:

```
$('#video-1').on('click', function() {
  $('#video-1').css('background', 'none');
  $('#video-1').css('display', 'block');
  $('#video-1').css('position', 'static');
  $('iframe').css('display', 'block').attr('src', function() {
    return edTalksAutoPlay();
  });
});
```

How / is there a way to achieve what I'm looking to do? Thanks!

Comment: You'll want to use classes instead of ids.  Also use 'this' keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to group the elements together. You can do that either by adding a class to them, or selecting them by a parent element, eg. `#parent > div`.

From there you can use the `this` keyword to refer to the element that raised the event within the handler. I would also strongly suggest you use pre-defined CSS classes to style the elements and use `addClass()`/`toggleClass()` to amend them. Something like this:

```js
$('.video').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active').prop('src', function() {
    return edTalksAutoPlay();
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: none;
  display: block;
  position: static;
}
```

```html
<div id="video-1" class="video"></div>
<div id="video-2" class="video"></div>
<div id="video-3" class="video"></div>
```

Finally, note that `div` elements do not have a `src` attribute - although I assume this was just an oversight when simplifying the HTML in your question.

Comment: Wonderful - that did it! Thanks for the help!

And good recommendation on appending the CSS via a class, I'll make that change. Also, you were correct on the SRC attribute, that actually populates an iFrame. Will update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

When jQuery invokes an event handler, it arranges for `this` to be bound to the DOM element involved. Thus, `$(this)` in the event handler will always give you a jQuery object for the element involved with the event.

```
$('[id^=video]').on('click', function() {
  $(this).css('background', 'none');
  $(this).css('display', 'block');
  $(this).css('position', 'static');
  $(this).css('display', 'block').prop('src', function() {
    return edTalksAutoPlay();
  });
});
```